# Rails 4 self-join adding where method to has_many causes errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a self-join that includes a `where` method filter.

To do so, I added `, -> { where location_type: 'Hospital' }` to the Model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :hospitals, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "parent_id", -> { where location_type: 'Hospital' }
  belongs_to :system, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "parent_id"

end
```

Unfortunately, this generates an error in the Rails Console:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > x = Location.find_by_id(1353)
SyntaxError: /Users/craibuc/Dropbox/Projects/Rails4/emr/app/models/location.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:422:in `load_file'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:323:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/craibuc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

The [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) indicates that a `where` clause is support for a `has_many`, perhaps it isn't supported for self-joins.  Can anyone confirm this?  Is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that lambda scope need to be specified before any other options supplied to the association declaration.

Please try:

```
has_many :hospitals, -> { where location_type: 'Hospital' }, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: "parent_id"
```